# Manual for 3Com SuperStack II NETBuilder?

Tags: router, 3com

I have a client with a 3Com SuperStack II NETBuilder (3C8432), and he wants me to set it up for him.  The only problem is that I have no experience with these routers and I can't find it's manual anywhere.

Does anyone know where I can find the manual for a 3Com SuperStack II NETBuilder (3C8432)?

Update:  I cannot connect to this thing via it's serial console not matter what combo of settings I try...  I need the docs, and neither HP (who now owns 3Com), nor the owner, has any docs on this device...  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suspect getting the NETBuilder working will cost as much as buying a replacement box; considering consultancy fees etc. A simple Cisco 1941 or similar would easily do the job of a NETBuilder 432 (unless you need legacy tokenring/FDDI interfaces etc).

However here are a couple of links for the software guides:

http://sysdoc.doors.ch/3COM/1/newinst.pdf

http://sysdoc.doors.ch/3COM/sw.pdf

Comment: Thank you for those...  They have helped immensely!  And yes, I think he should move to a more modern router too (although for his small business network, I would go with running pfSense or Untangle on server hardware, but that's just me).